# Include key value pairs in XSD schema generated from C# class

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have a class written in C#. This class is now going to be used in an API where an XML document is posted to the API. I need to generate a schema (XSD) to dictate the rules of the XML files that will be posted.

What I am really struggling with though is a way of annotating (?) my class so that the schema lists possible values for certain properties within the class. I'll be using "xsd.exe" to generate the XSD.

The possible values need to be listed as key value pairs. e.g. I have a property called Gender where the possible values are "M" and "F". These are obvious in that they mean "Male" and "Female".

What isn't so obvious is my property "StType" (street type). e.g. some valid values are "AC", "AL", "AN", "AP", "AR", and "AV". These correspond to "Access", "Alley", "Anchorage", "Approach", "Arcade", and "Avenue".

So what I want is a way to mark my class properties with key value pairs that will be translated to my schema. "XmlElementRestrictionsList" is made up below but I'm wanting something that does this sort of thing.

```
[XmlElementRestrictionsList{"M":"Male", "F":"Female"}]
public string Gender { get; set; }
```

This would in turn generate a schema something like

```
<xsd:element name="Gender" minOccurs="1">
    <xsd:restriction type="string">
        <xs:enumeration value="Male, M" />
        <xs:enumeration value="Female, F" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:element>
```

I don't know if that's actually how the schema writes it out but hopefully it's enough to get across what I am trying to achieve.

I've Googled a lot about string Enums but 1. I'm not entirely sure how to do this in my class and 2. more importantly, I have seen nothing that suggests key value pairs are an option. I DO NOT want my values corresponding to an Enum number ("M" = 1, "F" = 2).

And what is probably a really simple extra, how do I mark in the schema that something is required (in my class, ready for the schema generator)? Such as Gender, FirstName, and LastName (all strings in my class) must be included in the posted XML whereas Title and Phone can be missing entirely. I'm assuming that's what the "minOccurs" means. Although what I mean is required not minimum number of possibly multiple times.

```
[XmlElementRequired]
public string Gender { get; set; }
```

[EDIT]

Following on from class property settings works as it needs to except the actual generated schema. Which is what I am really after.

The C# cde generates a schema as follows:

```
<xs:simpleType name="Gender">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="M" />
    <xs:enumeration value="F" />
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

This, unfortunately, does not include my descriptions. How do I get the description in my schema?

What I really need is something like:

```
<xs:simpleType name="Gender">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="M" description="Male" />
    <xs:enumeration value="F" description="Female" />
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

I don't believe this is actually a part of the XSD standard so obviously that won't be possible. Hopefully it gets my point across though. Further research shows something about "annotations" but I do not know how to apply them to my enum values which in turn will be applied to my generated schema.

The short examples here have all been using gender which is easy to determine what the values mean. If, however, I am using my StType property the enumeration "value" is not so descriptive.

[EDIT 2]

It appears the generated schema I want should look something like this:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="Gender">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="M">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>Male</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:enumeration>
      <xs:enumeration value="F">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>Female</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:enumeration>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

My research seems to suggest this cannot be done using xsd.exe. So now I need to know what tool I can use to generate a schema with these annotations and what I have to put on my class property to ensure annotations are actually generated.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of playing with the various possibles I managed to get a working version.

Ultimately it was the "GetDescription" link that got me there in the end. The code at the top of that didn't help but a comment part way down did.

My final solution was to create the Enum as follows:

```
public enum Gender {
    [Description("M")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("M")]
    Male,
    [Description("F")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("F")]
    Female
}
```

Set my class property as follows:

```
public Gender Gender1 { get; set; }
```

Map my posted XML as follows:

```
Tools.GetDescription(data.Gender1);
```

Using the method below:

```
public class Tools
{
    public static string GetDescription(Enum en)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = en.GetType().GetField(en.ToString());
        DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =
              (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(
              typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

        return (attributes.Length > 0) ? attributes[0].Description : en.ToString(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Change your `Gender` field from `string` to `enum` type, as on listing, with `XmlEnumAttribute` at enum fields.

```
public enum Gender
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("M")]
    Male,
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("F")]
    Female
}
```

Check this [msdn doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2w0sxhf(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I just tried this but it doesn't work the way I need it to.

The XML is posted successfully but further on I need to set something else to a string value (mapping I am unable to change). Because my Gender is now an Enum it doesn't map to the string value I need it to. If I use Gender.ToString() it sets the value to "Male" but I need it set to "M".

I tried reversing the values in the Enum but then my XML posting fails.

I guess what I'm really after is a way of stating the required values are "M", "F" and as a "note" they mean Male and female. Is this even possible?

Comment: Add extra `[Description("F")]` and `[Description("M")]` attributes on fields in enum.

Comment: Then call `((DescriptionAttribute)attrs[0]).Description;` - but wrap it please :)

Comment: oo. here you've got `GetDescription` method - use it. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2005/10/20/c-enum-and-overriding-tostring-on-it.aspx

Comment: Same effect. :( ToString resolves to "Male" and
    [Description("M")]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("Male")]
        M 
causes my post XML to be NULL.

Comment: Don't use `.ToString` method. Get attribute value - check snippet in my link in previous comment

Comment: @DreadPeter Why did you unaccepted and did not upvoted my answer, with comments, which solved your problem ?

Comment: I unaccepted it because it didn't actually solve my issue (I got distracted by the steps and your answer solved an issue created by the process, which I am sure will be necessary to get the final result). It was close but ultimately I wanted the comments in the schema. The solution is great in dealing with enums and their description field in code. What I need though is a schema that shows the description for the enum values. "AC" shows up in the schema but does not explain this is for "Access". How do I achieve that was my original question.

Comment: Ok. Fair enought for me :)